# Linear Algebra - Complete solution for Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra

Alright, I'm having some trouble understanding the "**complete**" solution for Ax = b.

For instance, suppose

$$A = \pmatrix{ 1  & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 \\ 3 & 6 & 7 & 10}$$

I can already see that $Ax = \pmatrix{1 \\ 5 \\ 6}$ is a solution for this system but after elimination we get

$$A = \pmatrix{ 1  & 2 & 2 & 2 &b_1\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & b_2 - 2b_1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_3 - b_2 - b_1 0}$$

From there my textbook shows how to find a particular solution by setting all free variables to 0, yielding:

$$ x_1+ 2x_3 = 1$$ 
$$2x_3 = 3 $$

So that

$$x-particular = \pmatrix{-2 \\ 0 \\ \frac{3}{2} \\ 0}$$

It then claims that the **complete solution** to **Ax = b** is given by 
$$x-complete + x_n$$
where $x_n$ is a "generic vector in the nullspace",and since $$x_n = c_1 * \pmatrix{-2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0} + c_2 * \pmatrix{2 \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ 1}$$

$$x-complete  = \pmatrix{-2 \\ 0 \\ \frac{3}{2} \\ 0} +   c_1 * \pmatrix{-2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0} + c_2 * \pmatrix{2 \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ 1}$$

What I don't understand is:

- what is this "**generic vector in the nullspace**?
- Do we have to set the free variables to 0 and 1 respectively in order to find the nullspace? If not, how can this solution be considered complete if we're not describing all the possibles values the free variables could've taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $m>n$ the system $Ax=b$ has infinitely many or zero solutions depending upon the augmented RREF

$$A = \pmatrix{ 1  & 2 & 2 & 2 &b_1\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & b_2 - 2b_1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_3 - b_2 - b_1 }$$

Notably if $b_3-b_2-b_1\neq 0$ we have no solution otherwise the general solution is given by $x_P+x_H$ that is the sum of

- one particular soution to $Ax_P=b$
- the homogeneous solution to $Ax_H=0$